# Capture mouse clicks on WPF TextBox

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, textbox, mouseevent

I want to capture mouse clicks on a `TextBox`:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.Window1"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="300">
    <Grid>
        <TextBox x:Name="t" MouseDown="TextBox_MouseDown"
                 MouseLeftButtonDown="TextBox_MouseLeftButtonDown"
                 MouseLeftButtonUp="TextBox_MouseLeftButtonUp"
                 Height="50" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Now I only receive a mouse click event when the user first enters the `TextBox`. After this `TextBox` has keyboard focus, I do not receive mouse click event anymore. Any idea how to get this working?

Comment: Is ability to get focus is critical for you? Maybe you could disable it?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

[TextBox Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textbox.aspx)

> TextBox has built-in handling for the
> bubbling  MouseUp and MouseDown
> events. Consequently, **custom event
> handlers that listen for MouseUp or
> MouseDown events from a TextBox will
> not be called**. **If you need to respond
> to these events, listen for the
> tunneling PreviewMouseUp and
> PreviewMouseDown events instead, or
> register the handlers with the
> HandledEventsToo argument** (this latter
> option is only available through
> code). Do not mark the event handled
> unless you deliberately want to
> disable TextBox native handling of
> these events, and be aware that this
> has notable effects on the control's
> UI.

In you code you are firing just `MouseLeftButtonUp`

Comment: "MouseUp or MouseDown events from a TextBox will not be called" I think the real question is why these functions are even exposed at the api level in the first place, if this is indeed the case.

Answer (score 35):

You can use the PreviewMouseDown event, and capture any clicks that way before the internal parts of the control process the click:

```
<TextBox x:Name="t" PreviewMouseDown="TextBox_MouseDown" Height="32" Width="274" />
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's code example for those who are using MVVM

It works fine for events that are [inheriting from Control.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textbox_events(v=vs.110).aspx)

**In ViewModel:**

```
private ICommand _merchantRefereneceCommand;

public ICommand MerchantReferenceCopyToClipboard
    {
        get { return _merchantRefereneceCommand ?? (_merchantRefereneceCommand = new MerchantRefereneceCommand(this)); }
        set { _merchantRefereneceCommand = value; }
    }

public class MerchantRefereneceCommand : ICommand
    {
        private readonly PaymentViewModel _paymentViewModel;

        public MerchantRefereneceCommand(PaymentViewModel paymentViewModel)
        {
            _paymentViewModel = paymentViewModel;
        }

        public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
        {
            return true;
        }

        public void Execute(object parameter)
        {
            //Your code goes here.
        }

        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;
    }
```

**In View (xaml):**

```
<TextBox Grid.Row="1" x:Name="MerchantReference" MaxLength="10" IsReadOnly="True"
                             Text="{Binding MerchantReference, Mode=OneWay}"  >
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseDoubleClick" >
            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding MerchantReferenceCopyToClipboard}" />
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</TextBox>
```

Hope this saves you some time.