# Perform mouse click on TextBox or window

Tags: c#, wpf

I know that this is not a good practice, but I would like to simulate a mouse click event on a textbox, or a window in my wpf application.

I need this, because I am calling this application with some kind of interceptor and the window doesn't get the full focus, it is in front, textbox has a focus but u can't directlly type on textbox.

on window load I call these methods

```
this.Activate();
this.Topmost = true;
TextBox1.Focus();
Keyboard.Focus(TextBox1);
```

Thank you.

Comment: Here the solution for your question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1874394/capture-mouse-clicks-on-wpf-textbox

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue in VB. i just wanted the focus in the `SpinEdit1` (or any control) when the form load. Here is:

```
private void formX_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.ActiveControl = SpinEdit1;
}
```